# Controlling the installation of apk in wearable device

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I have installed an app on a handheld device, this app also has a wearable APK file inside it.

so the question is that if i have a connected wearable device then can i control the installing of the app to the wearable device or is it something that will happen at any cost?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean with control? The wearable portion of your app will be installed on the wearable automatically.

Comment: Is it possible to install the wearable application on a button click from the handheld application instead of installing it automatically

Comment: Not that I know of, why would you want to do that anyway? The user can't install just half of your app. If he already installed it then what reason is there not to install the whole thing? Obviously if the user made the decision to install it in the first place then he wants to use the whole app, not just part of it.

Comment: just want to know whether it is possible or not

Comment: As I said, not that I know of. And you shouldn't do that in the first place. I cannot imagine one reason why you would want to do that.

Comment: Yes but why? It's bad. There is no reason at all not to install it. For example why don't you just show no notifications on the smart watch? Just because it is installed doesn't mean it has to actually do anything. But not installing it will just cause problems when you get to the point at which you actually want to do something on the wearable. Aside from the fact to you cannot influence if the app is installed on the wearable in the first place.

Comment: If you don't want to display anything on the wearable then just don't display anything. The app will be installed on the wearable either way.

Comment: This matter is not discussed in developer.android site or even in any blogs. so just curious to know about this

Answer (score 1):

One reason is if you want to restrict access to your bundled wear app via an in-app purchase. I don't think the in app purchasing API is even available for Wear, so you would have to write to the DataLayer a flag to say if the feature is purchased or not, and disable the wear app's functionality unless purchased.

But the problem is the user will have a non-functional app in the app drawer on their watch until they pay for it. This would be pretty frustrating for users of my app who don't need/want it on their wrist.